# Is it possible to let Play Framework 1 handle a sent JSON in a post request?

Tags: java, json, parsing, playframework, request

Is it possible to let Play Framework 1 handle a sent JSON in a post request? The developer connecting to the backend would not like to send in key/value pairs with an ampersand as separator, he wants to send in a JSON. Problem is that the data is null, i.e `name` is null. Is this possible to achieve?

What I have so far:

**Controller**

```
public static void myMethod(String name) {
    Logger.info(name);
}
```

**Routes file**

```
POST    /test        Application.myMethod
```

And I send the request with header `Content-Type: application/json` and the data in the body `{
    "name": "A name"
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not find any auto binding so what I did was this:

```
MyModel myModel = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(new InputStreamReader(request.body), MyModel.class);
```

And it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't know how this worked with you, because it is to give the error: "Stream Closed". A workarround to this would be:

```
   String JSON = request.params.data.get("body")[0];
   MyModel myModel = new Gson().fromJson(JSON, MyModel.class);
```